# self Join operation

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I have a employee table contains `employeeID`, `name` and `ManagerID` - 3 columns, I want to write a query to display `name`, `managerName` and `level`, the Boss doesn't have `managerID`, its `managerID is null`.
See below table structure

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE #employee (
    EmployeeID int, 
    [Name] nvarchar(50), 
    ManagerID int
)

INSERT INTO #employee VALUES
(1,'Tom',2),
(2,'Josh',NULL),
(3,'Mike',2),
(4,'John',3),
(5,'Pam',1),
(6,'Mary',3),
(7,'James',1),
(8,'Sam',5),
(9,'Simon',1)
```

The effect I want to get:

[image]

How can I write the SQL query?

Comment: SQL Server or Oracle? It is to different DBMS. Please specify.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: just assume that this issue may exist in SQL server and Oracle. so how to figure it out

Comment: Oracle has an extra syntax for tree-queries like this, so it's essential to know the rdbms

Answer (score 1):

In **SQL Server** you can do this with recursive CTE:

```
;WITH rec AS (
SELECT  EmployeeID, 
        [Name], 
        ManagerID,
        1 as [Level]
FROM employee 
WHERE ManagerID IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT  e.EmployeeID, 
        e.[Name], 
        e.ManagerID,
        r.[Level] + 1
FROM employee e
INNER JOIN rec r
    ON e.ManagerID = r.EmployeeID
)

SELECT  r.[Name] as Employee,
        COALESCE(e.[Name],'Super Boss') as Manager,
        r.[Level]
FROM rec r
LEFT JOIN employee e
    ON e.EmployeeID = r.ManagerID
```

Output:

```
Employee    Manager     Level
Josh        Super Boss  1
Tom         Josh        2
Mike        Josh        2
John        Mike        3
Mary        Mike        3
Pam         Tom         3
James       Tom         3
Simon       Tom         3
Sam         Pam         4
```